# How to reverse sorting with \newrefcontext

Tags: biblatex

I am using package `biblatex` with `\newrefcontext` to sort.

Now I am using

```
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
```

and it seems that `biblatex` sorts articles from oldest to newest.

How can I sort the articles from newest to oldest?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
\newrefcontext[sorting=ydnt]
```